# mongodb sum the sub key/value pairs of a field

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate

I understand there are similar questions to this one on Stack Overflow, but the issue is that I cannot actually change the structure of the Mongo Schema. I have a document resembling the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asdfghjkl"),
    "recordId" : "0000_11111",
    "__v" : 0,
    "userid" : "0000",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-08-07T07:34:19.505Z"),
    "username" : "batman",
    "countries" : {
        "Philippines" : 1,
        "Lebanon" : 1,
        "Andorra" : 1,
        "Vanuatu" : 1,
        "China" : 2,
        "Greenland" : 2,
        "Denmark" : 1,
        "Hong Kong" : 1
    }
}
```

The list of countries is much larger than the example above, imagine up to 100 countries with numbers summing up to 500,000. I need an aggregate that can take the values of the list of countries and sum them up. I tried grouping and $sum but with no success.

Any quick solutions for this?

Thanks!
AK

Comment: It's it's only on a "single document" then you are wasting your time with the aggregation framework. Simply map the values from the object keys in code and sum them up. For JavaScript, presuming the document is in a variable called `doc`, then you simply do: `Object.keys(doc.countries).map(k => doc[k]).reduce((acc,curr) => acc+curr,0)`. It's a pretty common idiom in most languages. You don't bother asking databases to do such things with single documents at a time.

Comment: It is not a single document - its a huge amount of documents, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm talking about "aggregating **across** documents", which you do not actually ask to do in your question. So which question are you actually asking? Is it *"Sum the keys of each document and return the total for the **whole collection**?"*. Or is is *"Sum the keys of each document for **each of the** huge amount of documents"*? Because the latter case is not actually aggregation, and what your question actually implies.

Comment: My question was solved yesterday by felix below, thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: I do have eyes. And I'm telling you it's not much of a solution. If you think that works for you then simply applying the same expression as shown above to each document on the cursor does the same thing and **much** faster. Which if you actually tried it, then you would have worked that out by now.

Comment: it does work for me - thanks a lot, have a nice day